# BigQuery SQL: Using With clause before if statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a code which uses same data output that is produced within a 'With' clause in different conditions.
For example this works:

```
DECLARE x int64 DEFAULT 2;
IF x = 1 THEN
WITH test as ( select 32434 as column1, 45343 as column2)
SELECT column1 from test;
ELSEIF x = 2 THEN
WITH test as ( select 32434 as column1, 45343 as column2)
SELECT column2 from test;
END IF;
```

However I want to duplicate with clause and put it on the top of the code.
Something like this:

```
DECLARE x int64 DEFAULT 2;
WITH test as ( select 32434 as column1, 45343 as column2)
IF x = 1 THEN
  SELECT column1 from test;
ELSEIF x = 2 THEN
  SELECT column2 from test;
END IF;
```

This version does not work. What is the best to do this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: The WITH clause belongs to a SELECT. Use a case expression in the SELECT list instead of two separate SELECT's.

Comment: Can you give me a sudo code example for me to understand better?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE x int64 DEFAULT 2;
WITH test as ( select 32434 as column1, 45343 as column2)
SELECT 
  IF x = 1 THEN column1 
  ELSEIF x = 2 THEN column2 
END IF
from test;
```